# Mount /system RW / RO Android 7.1.1 Lenovo Tab 4 10"

Tags: android, root, tablet, kiosk-mode, superuser

I have a problem with making a /system folder into read/write permission. I made root (TWRP 3.2.3, SuperSU-v2.82 - in TWRP is unchecked read-only) and the problem is tablet freezes EVERY time a make change from RO to RW.

I used Root explorer, ES file explorer, Root file manager, Super manager... Every time when I change it and press "ok" tablet freezes. Also I try via terminal "mount -o rw,remount /system", nothing, a download apk "Mount system RO RW ROOT" and apk said it did it, by when I check in file explorer it is still read only. (also I try via fastboot and comannds pull and push and it said that file is read only)

I really need to make changes in /system/build.prop and I'm out of options...

Anyone?

Comment: Did you ever find out a reason for such behavior?